# How to send mail with SMTP relay?

Tags: python, email, outlook, smtp, office365

I am trying to send email using SMTP relay as mentioned in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#option-3-configure-a-connector-to-send-mail-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365-smtp-relay) Option 3. I have done every step as said in the article but I am not sure how to send mail after the step-up is done. Can someone please provide me the python code snippet to send emails via SMTP relay?

I know what we don't need to give password for sending mail because in powershell it is being sent by `Send-MailMessage` command.

Comment: the setup seems to be unrelated to python, so I suggest that You take a look at the [`smtplib` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) and watch some tutorials like this one (I suggest this one): [How to Send Emails Using Python - Plain Text, Adding Attachments, HTML Emails, and More by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRCJ6RtE3xU) and then come back when You have issues with Your code or provide a [mre] now. also read [ask] (I believe that this is not the case where code is not necessary)

Comment: the issue is everyone is using SMTP auth to send emails but not SMTP Relay

Comment: About relay, there was written in the link You provided, that relay does not support 3rd party apps or sth